# Erro ao fazer login: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

```js
/// minha rota de login
router.post("/login",  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, senha } = req.body;
      console.log(email, senha , "informacoes123");
      const loginUsuario = await clienteController.logar(email, senha);
      if (loginUsuario) {
        res.status(200).json({ mensagem: "Login bem-sucedido", usuario: loginUsuario });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ mensagem: "Credenciais inválidas" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao fazer login:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ mensagem: "Erro interno do servidor" });
    }
  });


//// função de logar 

 logar(req, res) {
  
    const { email, senha } = req.body;
  
    if (!email || !senha) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "As propriedades email e/ou senha não estão presentes em req.body." });
    }
  
    console.log(email, senha, "informacoesNovo");
  
    clienteModel.buscarLogin(email, senha)
      .then((usuario) => {
        if (usuario !== null) {
          res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login bem-sucedido' });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({ error: 'Credenciais inválidas' });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Erro ao fazer login:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro interno do servidor' });
      });
  }
  
/// função da model de buscar login

    buscarLogin(email, senha) {
        const sql = "SELECT email, senha FROM tblUsuario WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?";
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          conexao.query(sql, [email, senha], (error, resposta) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log("Erro ao buscar dados de login", error);
              reject(error);
            } else {
              if (resposta.length > 0) {
                console.log("Dados de login encontrados:", resposta);
                resolve(resposta[0]); // Retorna o primeiro resultado (assumindo que o email é único)
                console.log(resposta, "caiu 111");
              } else {
                console.log("Nenhum dado de login encontrado para o email e senha fornecidos.");
                resolve(null);
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Estás a passar o email e senha como argumentos da função logar() por isso o req e o res não existem.